# DB-ref in mongoose without Schema.ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in my code people can follow other people.
So far everything is ok apart from this fact: in the userScheme I have this field.

```
, following: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }]
```

Since every user has an username, it's more versatile for me to use dbref with the username.
is there a way to do something like this?

```
, following: [{ type: Users.username, ref: 'Users' }]
```

Many thanks,
g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only `ObjectId` values that refer to the `_id` property of another collection can be used as refs.

Confirmed in the [source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js).

Comment: isn't there any possible workaround that's so memory wasting because I have to search a file just to get the name :(

Answer (score 3):

You can only reference via ObjectId to a collection like your first code snippet.

```
[{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }]
```

When making a query with [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you can specify the fields you want to return. In your case, it woud look something like

```
User.find({}).populate('following', 'username').exec(function(err,doc) {});
```

Each object in the following array would look like

```
{ _id: 'xxxxxxxxxx', username: 'xxxxxxxx' }
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose's populate function is mongodb's lookup in the abstract but populate only creates refs to object id but if you are sure then you will have a unique username for every user and then if you want to populate data using username then you can use lookup and result will be the same.