# Alternate way to populate in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

How to use

```
senderId    : {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.username,ref:'User'}
```

instead of

```
senderId    : {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}
```

Please save my day.Thank u.If this is not possible then suggest me the alternative way to do this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to keep track using username

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280831/db-ref-in-mongoose-without-schema-objectid) it is explained that you cannot use something else than an ID to reference an other collection. @irok gave a nice explation about what to do :)